# Mocking classes which dont have interface and even no virtual methods

Tags: c#

I want to mock a particular method of a class, problem i am facing while mocking is that class does not have any interface and also that method is not virtual.

Can any one suggest any other way to implement mocking.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest refactoring your code ;) All mocking frameworks which creates mock by deriving from mocked class requires methods to be virtual (this is more CLR requirement rather than mocking framework).

To mock non-virtual methods you can use profiler-based frameworks like Moles or TypeMock Isolator, however this requires to run test runner using special runner which will attach CLR profiler to process

Answer (score 6):

Option 1: [TypeMock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) or something similar, which allows deeper messing with the code than normal mocking.

Option 2: (Preferred if possible) Alter the design, e.g. by introducing an interface and creating a delegating implementation which just calls into the existing test-unfriendly class. You can then depend on the interface, mock it in tests, and delegate to the "real" implementation for production.

This is assume you really *should* be mocking the class, of course. You shouldn't automatically mock *everything* your code uses - I tend to think of mocking "services" of some description, whereas I wouldn't mock (for example) `List<T>`.

Comment: What's the problem with option 1? That it is a non-open source tool? Or that it would *supposedly* lead to bad code/design? Any tool can be misused, and always *is* in one way or another, even the more conventional mocking tools with which people often mock mere "getters". "Alter the design by introducing an interface and creating a delegating implementation" is *more* likely to cause bad code, in my (biased) opinion.

Comment: sorry, I should have downvoted *after* commenting...

Comment: @Rogerio: I don't have much problem with it not being open source - although obviously it depends on the context. It wouldn't be much use in an open source project. Personally I would say that if this is genuinely something which *should* be mocked, introducing an interface would lead to a clearer design.

Comment: Yes, I imagined so. But I have found many cases where I didn't want to introduce a separate interface, even though I wanted to mock the class. One example: mocking business service classes used in presentation classes or in other service classes, where each service class contains business logic code specific to a single use case. More than not having a separate interface, I prefer to make such classes `sealed` (C#) or `final` (Java), and to instantiate them directly in the higher-level classes, with user-provided data.

Comment: @Rogerio: I think we'll just have to agree to disagree on this front. To me, if you want to have different behaviour in a test from in production, you should be calling a different implementation... or potentially creating the instance of that service class with fake dependencies underlying *that*. I'll give a counter-example: I found all kinds of things ended up cleaner when I adapted `WebClient` in Windows Phone 7. It actually meant I was able to switch from using `WebClient` under the hood to raw `WebRequest` when that turned out to be appropriate, with no client changes.

Comment: I don't think of mocked behavior as different from the one you get in production. Rather, you simply take control of the behavior of an interface (in this case, the implicit public interface of a concrete class) for the duration of a particular unit test, so that the actual implementation code behind that interface isn't executed. For all intents and purposes, the tested unit still sees the mocked class as having the "production" behavior (provided the test correctly specifies the desired behavior from the mocked class, according to its interface contracts).

Comment: `WebClient` is an infrastructure-level class, for which a higher-level wrapper may very well be useful in the context of a particular application; this is very different from the case of an application-specific business service class, however. Still, it [can](http://weblogs.asp.net/mehfuzh/archive/2010/10/06/how-to-raise-event-for-a-mocked-call.aspx) be easily mocked, if needed. My main point in all this, in the end, is that we should not rule out design options by default: if the developer believes there is good reason to mock a class, then a true mocking tool *should* support it.

Comment: I just imagine in an ideal world, we would be able to reserve interfaces and virtual methods for business use-cases and not testing.  Creating an interface for every class we want to test is just bloat, but the CLR being the culprit is understandable.

Answer (score 3):

There are unit testing frameworks such as [TypeMock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/download) that allow you to mock non-virtual members.

Comment: An alternative (though also comercial) is [JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

To purely mock out a legacy class I would do the following:

1. Create an interface containing the ONLY public members that I intend on using.
   eg.

   ```
   public interface IDbContext {
       int SaveChanges();
   }
   ```
2. If the target legacy class is sealed then I'd create a proxy/decorator class which implements the new interface and just invoked the underlying methods/properties.

   ```
   public class MyDbContextProxy : IDbContext {
       DbContext _context = null;
       public MyDbContextProxy(DbContext interceptedContext) {
           _context = interceptedContext;
       }
       // decorated method
       public int SaveChanges() {
           _context.SaveChanges();
       }
   }
   ```
3. If the target legacy class is not sealed I'd create a descendant of the target and implement the interface.  The class auto adheres to the interface.

   ```
   public class MyDbContextProxy : DbContext, IDbContext {
       // child adheres to interface by inheritence
   }
   ```

Now you can Mock out IDbContext.

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is something like Fakes Framework in VS2012. It's the successor of Moles (also able to mock classes etc. like TypeMock). It's available only in Ultimate edition, so I don't thnink it's worth Ultimate's price.

But, I'd like to discuss problem with mocking classes from other perspective.

Is it a good approach to mock classes instead of interfaces or it's some kind of a bad smell? I've never used TypeMock (it's too expensive to even consider it in small company), but people claims it's a bit "too powerful" so I'd like to use Moq/RhinoMocks, but sometimes I'd like to mock/fake one method and leave the others. It's my bad way of thinking about mocking/faking methods during tests? or it is sometimes required?

Comment: a late +1 for fakes framework :)